# Selecting an array item in handlebars by 'key'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to select an array item in handlebars by a key/field name?

Say my array was like so

```
"MyVariables": [
    {
      "Key": "var1",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Key": "var2",
      "Value": 2
    },
    {
      "Key": "var3",
      "Value": 3
    }]
```

I know it can be done by index eg

```
{{MyVariables.2.Value}}
```

However I would like something along the lines of

```
{{MyVariables.[Key == "var3"].Value}}
```

If it can't be done 'out of the box' does anyone know how it would be achieved with a helper?

I have searched high and low for this but cannot find a decent solution.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what it is that you're asking. Do you just want to get the object where `Key === "var3"` (`{Key:"var3", Value: 3}`)? Couldn't you just use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that? `MyVariables.find(item => item.Key === "var3").Value`. Or do you want to change the way the array looks so you can access it by using `MyVariables["var3"].Value` (Making the `Key` property the index).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way of do it is by change the struct of your array (**MyVariables**).

```
let MyVariables = [{
    "Key": "var1",
    "Value": 1
    },
    {
    "Key": "var2",
    "Value": 2
    },
    {
    "Key": "var3",
    "Value": 3
    }
];

let result = MyVariables.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.Key] = obj.Value;
    return map;
}, {});    

console.log(result["var3"])
```

In that case, **result** have the main data of **MyVariables** list but structured different, who let access to the required value easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [Lodash's Find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find)

Try `{{_.find(MyVariables, ['Key', 'var3'])}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way using `forEach`

```js
var arr= [
    {
      "Key": "var1",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Key": "var2",
      "Value": 2
    },
    {
      "Key": "var3",
      "Value": 3
    }]
    
    function value(key, keyValue, arr){
    var items= []
    arr.forEach((item)=>{
    if (item[key].indexOf(keyValue) != -1) // use indexOf or == its upp to you
        items.push(item)
    })
    return items;    
    }
    
    console.log(value("Key","var2", arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use `Array.prototype.reduce`, use extra variable if you don't want to change the original array.

```js
let MyVariables = [{
    "Key": "var1",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "var2",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": "var3",
    "Value": 3
  }
];

// use different variable if you don't want to change MyVariables
MyVariables = MyVariables.reduce((acc, val) => {

  acc = acc ? acc : [];
  acc[val.Key] = val.Value;
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(MyVariables["var1"]);
console.log(MyVariables["var2"]);
console.log(MyVariables["var3"]);
```